# Why downloaded videos by VidMate can only be played using PLAYit?

Tags: applications, video, youtube, media-player

I have downloaded a video from YouTube using VidMate. The video is in 1080p and is in MP4 format.

> [image]

When I tried to play it on mobile, it was not playing. I also tried it on PC using VLC Player, but it can't play the video too. Instead, the player shows this

> [image]

I tried converting it, but no video converter is able to convert it.

I researched VidMate and found out that it says "use PLAYit player to play the video". When I download the app, it plays successfully.

Why can downloaded videos by VidMate only be played using PLAYit even though it is in MP4 format?

Comment: Looking from [user reviews for 'PLAYit'](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.playit.videoplayer&showAllReviews=true) and searching for 'VidMate', looks like videos downloaded using VidMate are now encoded/encrypted so that it can only be played using PLAYit. I haven't tried examining the downloaded video in detail, but it already looks shady enough...

Comment: yes i have tried things like converting but no converter in converting that encrypted video, and unfortunately there is no decrypter is available yet. but the solution is that use some old version of vidmat and never update it.