# Video only playing in MX player

Tags: video, media-player, mx-player

I have downloaded a video (~400MB) in MP4. It only plays on MX player, and when I try to play it from the Files app or from PC, it instead shows a 9-second clip of (play in MX player).

What kind of programmable video container is this? How to play it with other players?

Comment: There is a [discussion about such videos of reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/uzgxso/unable_to_convert_strange_video_file_mx_player/) without result.

Comment: It would be better if you provide the link from where you downloaded this video, or at least share this video with us.

Comment: Related/similar situation with a different app: [Why downloaded videos by VidMate can only be played using PLAYit?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/223666/44325) (but not answered yet)